# Section title with background color and line breaks in KOMA

Tags: formatting, koma-script, backgrounds

[image: Goal]

I want my subsection title to have a colored background with support for line breaks. There are [a few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146443/color-background-for-chapter-titles-which-stretches-horizontally-to-the-margins?rq=1) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea) about spanning that background to the margins - that's not what I want to achieve, however.

After some research I found that the `soul` package comes pretty close to what I need, but I can't, unfortunately, seem to use its `\hl` command in KOMA's `\addtokomafont`.

Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{black}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\hl\mdseries\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{A very peculiar title which will hopefully break into the next line}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` (needs KOMA-Script Version 3.19 or newer) and `\subsectionformat`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{black}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}% only subsections should be changed
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2 #3}{\hl{#4}}}% subsection level
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2 #3}{#4}}% other section levels
}
\makeatother
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\mdseries\color{red}}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{\hl{\thesubsection\autodot}\enskip}

\begin{document}
\subsection{A very peculiar title which will hopefully break into the next line}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\hl` has some limitations. See the [documentation of package `soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul).

---

If you really want to use `\MakeUppercase` for the subsections you have to change the redefinition of `\sectionlinesformat` to

```
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsection}% only subsections should be changed
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2 #3}{\hl{\MakeUppercase{#4}}}}% subsection level
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2 #3}{#4}}% other section levels
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me for the most part. Ran into some weird error with `\MakeUppercase` in `\addtokomafont` (possibly related to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234801/uppercase-chapter-with-koma-script)), though. Anyway, since I'm auto-generating the TeX code, I can uppercase the text before writing the .tex file.

Comment: @hauptbenutzer Do not use `\MakeUppercase` in `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`. You can change `\sectionlinesformat` instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: Huh, why didn't I think of that. Thanks!